# Why does no three-scalar parameterization of 3d orientation exist that doesn't contain singularities?

Tags: reference-request, quaternions

I'm reading a magazine [article](https://www.chrishecker.com/images/b/bb/Gdmphys4.pdf) on 3d orientation and want to know what the mathematical issue is and where to read about it, preferably a theorem title that I can google or a topic and textbook:

> It’s possible to prove that no three-scalar parameterization of 3D
>   orientation exists that doesn’t suck, for some suitably mathematically
>   rigorous definition of “suck.” I haven’t done this proof (I think it
>   uses some pretty high-end group theory, which I haven’t learned yet),
>   so I can’t tell you exactly how it works, but I believe the gist of
>   the proof is that no minimal parameterization exists that doesn’t
>   contain singularities. These singularities can take different forms —
>   depending on how you allocate the three degrees of freedom — but
>   according to the math, it’s impossible to get rid of them.

3blue1brown [glazes over](https://youtu.be/d4EgbgTm0Bg?t=735) it by saying "As it happens, it's not possible to define a notion of multiplication for a 3d numer system like this that would satisfy the usual algebraic properties that make multiplicatiohn a useful construct" but goes no deeper. Saying he may make a future video. What is a good resource to understand the issue?

https://youtu.be/d4EgbgTm0Bg?t=735

Comment: You may be after "the hairy ball theorem" eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem. There are some videos around, and someone may be able to recommend a good one.

Comment: I think https://eater.net/quaternions/video/stereo3d starting at 4:06 might be an intuitive explanation of the issue but I'm not certain they are the same issue. This link explains degrees of freedom for rotations in 2d is 1 but in 3d is 3.

Comment: or it might be gimbal lock/euler rotations. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno

Comment: The article quote and the 3blue1brown quote seem unrelated to me. Why do you think they're related?

Comment: I'm guessing by "minimal parametrization" the author means identifying $SO(3)$ with a nice (e.g. open or closed) topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which carries a smooth group operation. Indeed, it's not possible to embed $SO(3)$ (which is, topologically, a projective space $\mathbb{RP}^3$) within $\mathbb{R}^3$, or even immerse it I'm guessing.

Comment: @runway44 Yes, he's definitely not referring to gimbal lock after watching all the videos. What would you suggest reading to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the 3D orientations are, in their essence (i.e. topologically), equivalent to the parameterization of a circle and a sphere.  You can see this in some of the representations such as the axis-angle or the quaternions.  But no matter the representation, to specify an orientation, you need to choose a point on a circle *and* a point on a sphere.  Sometimes it is not always clear that that is what you are doing but under the covers a rotation always chooses a point on a circle and a point on a sphere and with *any* representation you can always get back to these points.  The problem is then the parameterization of the sphere.  As mentioned in the comments, it is not possible to parameterize the sphere with two parameters and not have at least two singular points (i.e. hairy ball theorem).  Fortunately you can parameterize the sphere with three points and one constraint (i.e. a vector of unit length).